# Why is the superblock last mount time in the future?

Tags: 12.04

Future time:

Since installing Ubuntu 12.04, I regularly have to  fun fsck and reset my clock because it shows a 'future time' : Err.Msg. "superblock last mount time is in the future by less than a day, probably due to hardware clock being incorrectly set."
FIXED.

According to what I have read, it looks like I'm in the right place to get an answer. 
Following are my feeble attempts to rectify this annoyance:

```
mjh@mjh-desktop:~$ sudo service ntp start
[sudo] password for mjh: 
ntp: unrecognized service

mjh@mjh-desktop:~$ 
mjh@mjh-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update

mjh@mjh-desktop:~$ sudo service ntp start
ntp: unrecognized service
mjh@mjh-desktop:~$
```

Suggestions?

Matthew

Answer (score 4):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Once you install NTP, then you do

```
sudo service ntp start
```

Comment: Thank you!I have installed and started the ntp service and will see how thing go after a few start-ups and re-boots.